# How do I execute the containment tree command of Photos with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, photos

According to:

https://photosautomation.com/scripting/script-library-01.html

There's a command, for Photos, called containment tree. How do I execute it?

Answer (score 0):

> There's a command, for Photos, called containment tree.

I don't believe there is a **command** called containment tree, but instead a **class** called **container**. Maybe that's what you mean and in which case you would use it similarly to the code below.

```
tell application "Photos"
    set x to every container
end tell
```

It's quite possible I'm not understanding what you want to do though since you don't state your goal or what you're trying to accomplish.